# circular image flow using javascript

Tags: javascript

is there any free javascript library like  http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Examples#Enable_circular_mode for GPL License? i like the ciruclar mode image rotate, but they uses Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial 3.0 Unported License

Answer (score 0):

There are some jQuery based applications that will do a similar job. 
http://interface.eyecon.ro/docs/fisheye have a look here or google 'jQuery carousel'